# Personal backup solution that can handle a large number of files with a history view

Tags: windows, backup, windows-10

Does a Windows-based backup solution exist that maintains file history to a NAS and/or cloud-based storage (OneDrive, GDrive, etc)?  Bonus if it also supports Linux.

I've been a user of Windows 8.1 / 10 File History for quite some time.  It has some really nice features, but it also has a lot of shortcomings that makes you scratch your head and think "how could they not include that??" or "why does it do that??".  It's far from perfect and is very half-baked.

The backup solution I'm looking for has an easy to use UI to manage different scheduled snapshots of folders and files throughout time (similar to Win File History, but more usable).

In addition to maintaining historical snapshots of specified folders, I would like for it to essentially be like Windows File History, with the following additions...

- **Support excluding folders that match certain regex/wildcards** - *Win File History supports excluding a specific folder path, but I can't tell it to ignore any folder with the name "node_modules"*.
- **A coherent UI for restoring snapshots (a calendar view?)** - *Win File History has a pretty nice UI, until you actually try to use it.  If you have 400 days of history, you have to click "previous" 400 times to get to day 1 - no calendar view*
- **Ability to store snapshots to cloud storage** such as OneDrive, Google Drive, or DropBox.
- BONUS: In addition to Windows, support for Linux as a source would be great.
- BONUS: In addition to cloud storage, SMB / NAS storage would be great, but in a less fragmented way than Windows File History.  What I mean is: I can't have it store an individual file for every version of every file throughout history.  I recently ran out of i-nodes on my Linux NAS and it's a constant fight (1.9 million files).  Some sort of database format or something would be better

Does anyone know if a magical backup/restore solution such as this exists?

Thanks

Comment: since i don't know *Windows File History* and don't use the software myself, just a comment: it sounds to me that [Duplicati](https://www.duplicati.com/) is worth a look; there is also an [older stable version](https://sites.google.com/a/duplicati.com/duplicati/home)...

Answer (score -1):

AJC Sync might help you it can backup to NAS or cloud locations and optionally keeps a history archive for each file so you can undo back to any version that was deleted or overwritten during the sync process.  So its snapshot is on a per file basis.  Also the history archive needs to be on the network so it can go on a NAS.
See [AJC Sync](http://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm)